# How to display arraylist objects in jsp using session.getAttribute

Tags: java, arrays, session

I am trying to display the objects in an ArrayList defined in my servlet in the jsp file using session.getAttribute() to retrieve the ArrayList.

```
<%= String name= (String[]) session.getAttribute("studentObject"); %>
```

This is my current code in the jsp display file and the error says "Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation". The syntax looks okay to me. Any idea what the error is ?

I defined an ArrayList which consists of student objects which I wanna display. This is how I retrieved it:

```
     String student_name = request.getParameter("studentName"); 
     ArrayList<Object[]> studentList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
     if(student_name != null && student_name.length() > 0) {
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from users where firstname LIKE ? ");
  preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" +student_name+ "%");
  ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  while (resultSet.next()) {
      String first_name = resultSet.getString("firstname");
      String last_name = resultSet.getString("lastname");
      String email = resultSet.getString("email");

      Object[] student = {first_name,last_name,email};
      studentList.add(student);
      //System.out.println("First Name: " + first_name + "," + "Last Name: "           + last_name);
  }
  session.setAttribute("studentObject",studentList);
  //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentList.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= String name= (String[]) session.getAttribute("studentObject"); %>
```

your declartion is wrong in here. you assigned your `session.getAttribute("studentObject")` into a string of Array. your **session.getAttribute("studentObject")** is an ArrayList thats why you got it wrong. Remove the equal sign `<%=` on your scriplet because you are on declaration phase.

Just change it to this:

```
<% ArrayList<Object[]> name= (ArrayList<Object[]>)session.getAttribute("studentObject"); %>
```

And if you wanna get the array of student list in your arraylist. See below:

```
<% for(Object[] tempStudentList: name) {
    System.out.println(tempStudentList[0],tempStudentList[1],tempStudentList[2]);
} %>
```

you cannot cast it to `array of String` because `array of Object` can have different data type on its element. You can cast the Object to String in every element when you retrieve it. here is the Sample:

```
<% for(Object[] tempStudentList: name) {
    for(Object tempStudent : tempStudentList) {
         String student = (String) tempStudent;
         System.out.println(student);
    }
} %>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but there is an error saying "the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: I just edited it, I change String to Object[]. I didnt notice it. sorry

Comment: Hi, i am still getting the same error of "the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable" and also this error "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" and a couple of other errors. :(

Comment: I got it. just remove the equal sign in your scriplet.

Comment: got it thanks, but when I am trying to display the students, i have an error saying an exception occurred in the line "String[] studentList = (String[]) tempStudentList;" Do you have this error ?

Comment: what is the exception you encounter?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: Ow I See. it is because The object array can have different data types on its element. just dont cast it to String. instead you directly retrieve it in a form of Object. I will edit my post.